# How to use action /user/profile/show in label?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I just want to add Profile in navbar for logged user.
And I found /user/profile/show in dektrium yii2-user docs.

But it said:

> Displays user's profile (requires id query param)

How to implement /user/profile/show in label that requires id query param?

Thanks in advance

```
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/user/registration/register']];
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/user/security/login']];
} else {
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Profile', 'url' => ['/user/profile/show']];
    $menuItems[] = '<li>'
        . Html::beginForm(['/user/security/logout'], 'post')
        . Html::submitButton(
            'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
            ['class' => 'btn btn-link']
        )
        . Html::endForm()
        . '</li>';
}
```

When I use code above and click the Profile navbar, it said Bad Request (#400), Missing required parameters: id. Yea I know becuse of the id query param isn't defined.

Comment: Please add related code.

Comment: OK, I already added where the code might put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `id` to params like so:

```
$menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Profile', 'url' => ['/user/profile/show', 'id' => $id]];
```

`url` parameter is processed with [Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail) method in case of array, so you can pass additional parameters as key-value pairs.

Comment: Ah.. So that's how we set query param, right? Thanks!